# Can two apps have the same name if spacing is different

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

Can two apps have the same name in the app store as long as there is a slight difference? For example if there was an app that already existed called "FatCat" would an app get approved that was called "Fat Cat" with a space?

Comment: So, what is it you want.  Some people to buy your app, thinking it is the other one?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the availability of a name of app regardless of its origin, spelling or grammar before even creating the app. Log in to iTunes Connect — Click Manage Your Applications -> Add New App (don't fill in a SKU Number or bundle ID); if the name is already taken, you will get the following errors:

> You must select a Bundle ID.
>   The App Name you entered has already been used
>   provide a SKU.

Act accordingly based on the errors. But AFAIK, without doing all that, the algorithm segregates the two so you should be safe with a space between it since it considers FatCat as one word, unless someone has already reserved it but has not yet submitted it to the App Store or is not yet live in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

You can create an app with the same name or similar name by following things:

- Make a slight change by adding space. punctuation mark etc.
- By selecting Different Primary language when creating a new application. using this way you will be able to create the app with ditto same name.